# SSIS insert recrods from Oracle to SQL and even process them

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis

Thanks for answering...

I am new to SSIS and I have below requirement:

1. We are getting bulk records from Oracle based on some criteria.
2. I need to insert all these bulk records first to an audit table in SQL server The tables has only few columns. the reason for this is we will get to know how many records in each cycle we have got from oracle and if they are pilling up what is the exact reason.
3. After inserting in audit table, I need to process them one by one in SQL server and at the end of processing I would be either accepting the record and inserting the entire record in SQL serever or rejecting the record in SQL server based on business condition.

Currently to implement this I have first added a Data flow task in SSIS package which selects few columns(which are required by Audit table) from the Oracle and inserts them to SQL server after conversion. Than I am again getting the records from oracle using SQL execute task and processing them one by one using for each container in sql server.

As mentioned above I am making twice the call to Oracle, I am not able to reduce this to one?

can someone please guide me how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would you insert a partial set of data then extract the full set of data from the partial set? If you want to make it one process you will need to reverse your processes or keep them as 2 parts.

Comment: would it be possible to get the data once from oracle loop them and store in audit table and then again loop them again and process the record. I am not sure if SSIS would permit to loop the same enumerator twice in two loops  and whether that would give better performance?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the data already in SQL (you did a bulk copy in your audit table) you can take the data from there and do the insert in the table you want.

Instead of reading the data from Oracle twice, you can use your SQL Execute Task to manipule the data in SQL. You can make the insert statement from here to the final table.

Comment: I wont be having all the columns in audit table. it has only 5 columns.

Comment: Then why would you audit the records before inserting them? Wouldn't it be better to audit the records that were accepted?

Comment: I need to insert all the records which have came from Oracle whether they are getting processed or not that would depend on business criteria. But this kind of log/audit where it would maintain all the records.